# Who are these characters/superheroes in the posters from Chris's room in Family Guy?

Tags: character-identification, super-hero, family-guy

In Chris's room in *Family Guy* we see some posters of superheroes. I could identify one of them as [Triton](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Triton_(Earth-616)) from Marvel comics

[image: green Triton]

But I'm not able to recognize the three other characters (*marked in red boxes in images below*)

[image: three unknown Characters]

Are these actual fictional characters that appear somewhere? If yes, who are they?

---

Some closer-up pictures:

Poster #1:
[image: Poster #1]

Poster #2:
[image: Poster #2]

Poster #3:
[image: Poster #3]

Bonus, Triton poster:
[image: Triton poster]

Comment: Hawkman? https://cartoonscrapbook.com/cartoonscrapbooksupersite/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/hawkman-1967_L42.jpg

Comment: Godzilla next to the fish tank makes me wonder if the posters show Japanese heroes and villains.

Comment: Uh... What is going on in the last picture?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen [asked and answered on Movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/92498/63559). Basically it's a reference to *Jurassic Park*, with the "folding cowl" dino spitting goo at the villain.

Comment: The blue chap appears to have a wrecking ball for a hand.  Did Spider-Man or Daredevil have an opponent like that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The creators of Family Guy probably didn't invest too much money and effort into small pieces of background props like these. Therefore, I'd assume that they didn't use any actual characters, for which they would have needed to pay licensing fees, negotiate how the characters may and may be not be used and so forth.

I'd assume they rather drew up some "superhero-y" figures who have the typical attributes many "real" superheros have. The first one seems to pick up the "bird prototype" like for example [Hawk Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawkman) or the [Winged Bird-Men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Vultan) from Flash Gordon.

The second one goes for the "animalistic/force of nature plus muscles, and more muscles" variant, like [Beast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beast_(comics)) (especially how he looked in the 90s), [Hulk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hulk) or [Thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thing_(comics)). The third one is probably a [Silver Surfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Surfer) with a different color scheme. The one you connected to Triton might also have a bit of [Swamp Thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swamp_Thing) in its line of ancestors.

So, they're probably no actual characters, but generic figures that transport the idea "Chris is into superheroes".

Answer (score 12):

1) Follows the general appearance of a sea creature that appears in various media.  I'm not aware if that is a specific character.  e.g. [Creature from the Black Lagoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creature_from_the_Black_Lagoon), [Scooby Doo - Sea Demon](https://scoobydoo.fandom.com/wiki/Sea_Demon)

[image: Sea Demon]

2) Could be a [Birdman](https://superfriends.fandom.com/wiki/Birdman) costume variant.  Although there are other similar heroes like [Hawkman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawkman), as commented by Valorum.

[image: Birdman]

3) <strike>Appears to be [Beast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beast_(comics)), from the X-men.</strike>
Definitely not with the close up picture.  Keeping for posterity.
[image: Beast]

4) Seems familiar, but I can't place them.

Comment: Uh, never noticed that Beast and Machoke had the same outline: purple-blue, all muscle, black briefs and gold belt. In hindsight I guess it's tropey though

Comment: @Jenayah Indeed.  My first gut reaction was actually [Panthro](https://thundercats.fandom.com/wiki/Panthro) from Thundercats, who also looks similar.

Comment: 4) Looks very much like Space Ghost riding a surfboard SilverSurfer style.

Comment: Either Beast or a blue Hulk, yes.

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer: the second one certainly looks like the Pokémon [Machoke](https://www.bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Machoke_(Pok%C3%A9mon)). Bulky, purple skin, black underwear with golden belt.

[image: Machoke]

Comment: Is it underwear if it's worn that way?

Comment: @PeterM that's the underwear paradox: you never know what color it is until it's not "under"wear anymore.

Comment: But has Machoke ever been seen wearing pants or a dress or anything?!?!?!

Comment: @PeterM so I googled "Machoke pants" and found out that... My premise is flawed. Machoke doesn't wear underwear/pants, those are skin color patterns. [No, really, it's official](https://soranews24.com/2015/12/01/official-pokemon-site-reveals-bizarre-yet-amusing-secrets-about-fighting-type-pokemon-machamp/). You learn something new everyday...

Comment: LOL which also makes my question flawed!

Comment: @PeterM It's not underwear. The correct name for this type of garment is 'trunks'. As in swimming trunks and also worn by circus performers.

Answer (score 0):

The Blue Dude is [A-Bomb](https://hulk.fandom.com/wiki/A-Bomb), a Marvel Character from the Hulk Comics.

Seth Green does his voice for "*Hulk and the agents of Smash*"

Comment: An image would improve this answer